# can't input value for string?

Tags: java, string, variables, netbeans

I have been trying to convert an object to a string and then have that string value assigned to a string I have already defined.

Currently I have this

```
public static final String stringthing;
```

^ so at the beginning of the code I have pretty much said I have a string but I haven't assigned a value to it.

When I try to convert an object to string and then set that string equal to my unassigned string value "**stringthing**"  I keep getting "unexpected type, found value require variable".  The thing I don't understand is why can't I assign that string value to **stringthing**?

```
for (Object student : students) {
    System.out.println(student.toString())=stringthing;
}
```

I have seen other topics regarding "unexpected type, found value require variable" in which I only saw things orienting around integers, however I don't understand why this isn't legal or okay in Java?  Is there something syntax-wise that I don't understand?

Comment: `System.out.println()` is not a `variable` it is a `method`. You can't assign anything to `System.out.println()`.

Comment: You could however do this `stringthing = student.toString();System.out.println(stringthing);`

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is a very basic question, there is nothing wrong in this. It's a very valid question with all details.. So why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(...);
```

Does print a string to stdout

if you want to assign student.toString() to stringthing, then do :

```
stringthing = student.toString();
```

And after you can do :

```
System.out.println(stringthing);
```

Comment: **Print** a string to std**in**?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(student.toString())
```

That is a method call that prints what ever `student.toString()` returns. You can't assign a value to that method call. That is simply not possible.

You have a big mix up there. What ever you try, you are doing it wrong in every possible way.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Foo {

    public static String stringthing;
    public static List<Object> students;

    // [...]

    public static void bar() {
       for (Object student : students) {
         stringthing = student.toString();
         System.out.println(stringthing);
      }
   }
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

First you cannot reset the value of a final variable, so it has to be "non-final". Second the assignment was wrong.

Comment: basically it looks like that's what I'm trying to do.   I'm just trying to get student converted to string and then be stored into "stringthing".